# A problem of the use of prepositions "at", "in" in certain contexts

Tags: prepositions

The patterns:

1. I work at the kitchen in a restaurant.
2. I work at the kitchen in the restaurant.
3. I work in the kitchen at a restaurant.
4. I work in the kitchen at the restaurant.
5. I work at a kitchen in a restaurant.
6. I work at a kitchen in the restaurant.
7. I work in a kitchen at a restaurant.
8. I work in a kitchen at the restaurant.

What is the difference between these sentences in meaning? Which of them are ungrammatical and must be crossed off?

Comment: Idiomatically we don't use preposition *work **at** a/the kitchen* (it's always "container metaphor" ***in***). We wouldn't attach the definite article to *the restaurant* unless that particular restaurant had already been identified within the conversation, but it's normal to refer to ***the** kitchen in/of/at **a** restaurant* (where using the indirect article ***a** kitchen* might imply the restaurant has multiple kitchens). There's no particular "standard" preposition to precede *restaurant* in your exact context here (note that there's nothing "unidiomatic" about repeating ***in*** here).

Comment: Save yourself some grief and just say ***I work in a restaurant kitchen.***

Comment: Thank you! So, "I work in the kitchen at/in a restaurant as a cook" will sound good? And using "at" or "in" won't make any difference?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also *I work in the kitchen **of** a restaurant as a cook*, and perhaps more naturally, *I work as a cook in a restaurant kitchen*.  All these variations are fine (and I expect at least *some* people won't mind you saying you  *work **at** the kitchen*, but I'm not keen on that).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can I ask a pair more questions, please? Which of the prepositions and articles are to be used with words like: post-office, railway-station, port, airport, hospital, barber's shop, shop,  office, factory, cafe (I work at/in...)?

Comment: In general, you use the definite article if the *specific* station / airport / hospital / whatever is contextually obvious, otherwise use the indefinite article (but there will be exceptions, so don't get *too* fixated with that as a "rule"). Also *in general*, you work ***at*** a "place" (seen as a "location", rather than a "container" as with *working **in** the kitchen*). If the place feels more like a container / room, consider using ***in***, but your default should be ***at***. For many contexts, such as *The boy is **in / at** school*, both forms are equally natural.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I often stumble across different variants of use of at/in with the same words. For example: "She works in a post-office", "She works in a railway-station", "He works in the X District court of the city of Y". Cases of this kind don't add up for me. Of course, I would prefer "at". But why is it "in"? I don't pick it up to the fullest.

Comment: *post office, railway station, the X District court...* are all places that could be referenced using either ***at*** or ***in***. You can get an idea of which preposition is most likely for any given "place of employment" by running a [Google NGrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) with a "wild-card" asterisk in place of the preposition - for example **worked * the post office** (I can't put the actual link to that one in here because it's too big for a comment). Note that ***airport*** is a bit unusual, because unlike most "workplaces", it's relatively *very* uncommon with ***in***.

Comment: Oh, I see. The main problem is that in books on English Grammar written by non-native linguists (they are usually world-wide acknowledged professors) they try to foist rigid rules on students. For example: with the definite article we ought to use "at", i.e. "I work at the post office" ("the" conveys the idea that post office is regarded as a type of a facility and not as a certain building). And "in" with an "a" article, i.e. "I work in a post office". Another rule:  if a facility is designated for rendering services to people we use "at" as well as when a man does some temporary work there.

Comment: I.e. "Now I am working at the post office". And "in" for working there as an employee. I.e. "I work in the post office ( on a permanent basis)". Strange?